# A subbase of the weak topology of $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, metric-spaces

1. Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *coarsest* topology on $X$ such that each
   $$
   f_{i}:(X, \tau) \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)
   $$
   is continuous. It follows that $\{f_i^{-1} (O_i) \mid i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i\}$ is a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition) of $\tau$.
2. Let $X$ be a metric space with be Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. Let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the set of probability measures on $(X,\Sigma)$. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), the weak topology $\tau_w$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is generated by
   $$
   \mathcal U :=\left\{ U_{\phi, x, \delta} \,\left|\, \begin{array}{c} \phi \colon X \to \mathbb{R} \text{ is bounded and continuous,} \\ x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \delta > 0 \end{array} \right. \right\}
   $$
   where
   $$
   U_{\phi, x, \delta} := \left\{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}(X) \,:\, \left| \int_{X} \phi \, \mathrm{d} \mu - x \right| < \delta \right\}.
   $$

It is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63567/basis-for-topology-of-weak-convergence-of-probability-measures) that $\mathcal U$ is a **base** of $\tau_w$. It seems to me $\tau_w$ is the initial topology induced by the collection of maps
$$
\left\{L_\phi:\mu \mapsto \int_X \phi \mathrm d \mu \,\middle\vert\, \phi \colon X \to \mathbb{R} \text{ bounded and continuous}  \right\}.
$$
As such, $\mathcal U$ is indeed a **subbase** of $\tau_w$.

> Could you confirm if my above understanding is correct?